# modify values of a pandas column that contains nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have't find questions like mine...

btw I have a df with a column `Year` like this:

```
    2009)
    1998)
    2000)
    1980)
    2002)
    nan
    nan
    nan
    2014)
    1973)
    nan
```

I want to cut off the parenthesis, but when I use  `data['Year'] = data['Year'][:-1]` nothing happens (not even errors)

If I use `data['Year'] = data['Year'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])` it gives me

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I guess that the problem are "nan" values, but how can I fix the problem?
It should be ok to convert nans in 0.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try string replace and chain fillna to remove NaNa

```
df.Year=df.Year.str.replace('[\(\)]','').fillna(0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
data['Year'] = data['Year'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if isinstance(x, str) else '')
```

After else you can put what value you want to appear if it's not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas implements a [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str) property to manipulate text data.

```
data['Year'] = data['Year'].str[:-1]
```